# Multiple UDP clients send packets to one host doesn't work

Tags: java, android, networking, udp

I have a simple UDP server running on one device, when a client wants to connect, it sends the server a message "connect", the server then takes the address, and starts to send data to that address, now when another client wants to join, that client sends the message "connect" but sometimes nothing happens, it's like the client that wants to join message never gets received by the server, how would I fix this? Also here is the code for the server

```
 protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    boolean run = true;
    String data = "";
    DatagramPacket packet = null;
    boolean position = false;
    while( run )
    {
        if( data.equalsIgnoreCase( "" ) )
        {

        }

        //Send some data
        if( data.equalsIgnoreCase( "connect" ) && wait == true )
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Someone wants to connect");
            //Increase the total players by 1
            players = players + 1;
            //Notify to the host (client) something has change
            //notify client
            //Send a message to the client with the ID
            byte[] bufer = new byte[256];
            //Send a message "connect" to the host
            String msg = Integer.toString( players );
            int msgLength = msg.length();
            bufer = msg.getBytes();
            InetAddress address;
            //Default ip address of the host
            //Take the address from the packet
            addresses.add( packet.getAddress() );
            Log.d(TAG, "Address is " + addresses.get( addresses.size() - 1 ) );
            address = addresses.get( addresses.size() - 1 );
            DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket( bufer, bufer.length , address, port );
            //Send packet
            try 
            {
                socket.send( p );
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            wait = false;
        }

        if( wait == true && position == true )
        {
            position = false;
            wait = false;
        }

        for(int i = 0;i < positions.length; i++)
        {
            if(positions[i] != null)
            {
            //Log.d(TAG, "X and Y position of asset:"+i+", is:"+ positions[i]);
            }
        }

        //Needs to try and reteive data...
        if( wait == false )
        {
            //Log.d(TAG, "Waiting to retreive data");
            byte[] buf = new byte[256];
            packet = new DatagramPacket( buf, buf.length );
            try 
            {
                socket.receive( packet );
                wait = true;
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error with receiving data");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            data = new String( buf, 0, packet.getLength() );
            //Log.d(TAG, "Data received from :" + packet.getAddress() + ", holds this value: " + data);
            String[] dataStrings = data.split(":");
            if( dataStrings[0].equalsIgnoreCase( "position" ) )
            {
                position = true;
            }
        }



        //Log.d(TAG, "Data received was :" + data);

        /*try 
        {
            Thread.sleep( 25 );
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.d(TAG, "Error with trying to sleep");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Error with while run value");
    return "finished";
}
```

Client code to connect to the server

```
public void connectToServer()
{
    //Send a connect message to the server
    try {
        //Create a socket
        socket = new DatagramSocket( port );
        byte[] bufer = new byte[256];
        //Send a message "connect" to the host
        String msg = "connect";
        int msgLength = msg.length();
        bufer = msg.getBytes();
        InetAddress address;
        //Default ip address of the host
        address = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.59");
        DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket( bufer, bufer.length , address, port );
        //Send packet
        socket.send( p );

    } catch (UnknownHostException e2) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Unknown host");
        e2.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Socket problem");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "I/O problem");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //Receive the message back
    byte[] buf = new byte[256];
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket( buf, buf.length );
    //Try to receive a packet from the server
    try 
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "Waiting for data");
        socket.receive( packet );
    } 
    //Error
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error with receiving data");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //Convert the packet to a string
    String data = new String( buf, 0, packet.getLength() );

    //Use the string to find out what ID this client is
    ID = Integer.parseInt( data );
    //Setup the client game
    setUpClient();
}
```

Should I try and get the connectToServer method to keep trying if something isn't right?

Canvas

Answer (score 0):

The client doesn't send anything to the server after the first 'connect' String. Thus the server waits forever at that line:

```
 socket.receive( packet ); // <- will never return
 wait = true;
```

Anyways, you should avoid using AsyncTask for long running tasks such as a server recv() loop, and refactor the server code for the different cases (receive a 'connect' message, or a message from an already known client).

Comment: I'm working on that now, Also I'm using AsyncTask as it is on Android devices, and some of them are running on ver4 and above, and threads can't be used via GUI, I will of course check the code once I get everything working fine, just want to get stuff working :)

Comment: oohh also the clients will keep sending data to the server once they have connected, I didn't show the code as that is not the problem

Comment: So what is happening is, the client that is already connected is keeping the socket receive busy, and the new client can't send connect, because it is busy.